# JavaScript code issue

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, inventory, game-development

So I am reading this book called "The Web Game Developer's Cookbook", and I stumbled upon a really difficult piece of code. It is just a program to drag and drop images to a 'player inventory' to store it in the main game character's bag.
Here is the code-

```
var draggingObject;
function handleDragStart(e) {
    draggingObject = this;
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
    var dragIcon = document.creteElement('img');
    var imageName = this.firstChild.id;
    dragIcon.src = imageName + '.png';
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragIcon, -10, 10);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (draggingObject != this) {
        var draggingGrandpa = 
            draggingObject.parentElement.parentElement;
        var draggedToGrandpa = 
            this.parentElement.parentElement;
        var draggingObjectId = 
            draggingObject.firstChild.id;
        inventoryObject.add(draggedToGrandpa.id, draggingObjectId);
        inventoryObject.remove(draggingGrandpa.id, draggingObjectId);
        draggingObject.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = 
            e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
            this.classList.remove('empty');
            draggingObject.classList.add('empty');
    }
}

var itemBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.inventory-box');
[].forEach.call(itemBoxes, funtion(itemBox) {
    itembox.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
    itembox.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
    itembox.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
});
```

So first of all, I am really confused about the 3rd line of code, which is

```
    draggingObject = this;
```

So in this case, what is {this}? Is it just the element name that is being referred to from itemBoxes or is is something completely different?
It said that 'this' was the drop position of the inventory, or the position in which the item will be dropped.

Also, why do you really need 'grandpa'? Later on in the code, it talks about great-grandparents, and I thought we were only moving the div which the image is held in.

My main question is in the 3rd function (handleDrop). In the third line of this function, draggingObject must be equal to this (as it was set equal to this in function handleDragStart). In this case, the code in the if block will not execute.

Can someone please help me with this problem? I am extremely confused and really need help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`handleDragStart` is called in the context of the `itembox` when you start dragging it. `this` is the `itembox` element.

Edit: I'm not sure about that if statement in `handleDrop`. There must be some more context to it. Why not test this and set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

For your "main" question... that 3rd line... seems like it is going to replace whatever is in that "slot" with the draggED object.

It might be hard to read the difference between the draggED and draggING -- bad choice of words I think -- too easy to overlook.

When an object gets dropped, everything under the mouse will get pinged. This is due to a thing called "bubbling". Think like all the stuff on the page are a stack of crackers. If you push down real hard on the stack of crackers, all the crackers in the stack will be affected.

Likewise the mouse pings all the element that are underneath the mouse, actually both on the mouse down and the mouse up, as well as drag, drop, move etc. everything under the mouse receives the events.

So in that function you'll see the inventory "ADD" the draggED grandpa and "REMOVE" the draggING grandpa.

Here's some more crap I wrote that may or may not be useful:

In javascript the HTML "DOM" gets converted into "javascript world". So each HTML element is converted into a javascript "object".

A javascript object that represents an HTML DIV is a very complicated "thing" and so "this" is that complicated "thing".

So where ever you see a "this", there will usually be dot something attached to this.

For example:

```
this.innerHTML
this.firstChild
this.classList
```

And this is how we javascript people interact with stuff on the page.

So in the code, when dragging starts, they're flagging which thing is being dragged by making the draggingObject variable reference this thing that the user started dragging. And when the user stops dragging (drops the item) they're checking to see if the thing that was dropped is the same thing that the user started dragging.

Computers and programs can't magically read the mind of the person using it. Programmers have to be very explicit and tell the program how to do every single little thing -- like the computer is an infant that has no clue about anything.

The grandpa is a freindly way the author decided to refer to the image (or DIV or other HTML elememt) in the page that the draggable thing is inside of.

For example, HTML is a heirarchy, with images and paragraphs and DIV's all inside each other:

```
<div id="grandpa">
    <div id="dad">
        <div id="son">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So without reading the entire code you have on hand, I would guess that "grandpa" is probably the chest (like in minecraft) and greatGrandpa may be a room or maybe the personal inventory or somethign like that.